# Maintain aspect ratio on window resize: Flexible layout, with max and min dimensions

Tags: css, layout

Say I want the layout below.

I'd like to make the layout flexible to so that it resizes when the window does, but the container div holds it's aspect ratio. I want the container to also have max and min dimensions.

- Aspect ratio: 16:9
- Min: 1280x720
- Max: 1920x1080

For testing purposes I've been using:

- Min: 640x360
- Max: 1280x720

I want the container div to be vertically center at all times.

If you're familiar with the 'letter box' that shows when a 16:9 film is on a 4:3 TV, then that's the effect I'm going for.

I'm looking for a solution and a thorough explanation.

Here is a jsfiddle of what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/4qS7m/9/

Thanks!

---

- I've found a solution to keep the aspect ratio: http://alistapart.com/d/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video/example2.html
- I've also added the max/min dimensions.

**TODO**:

- Vertically center main div

---

**Layout**:

[image]

**HTML**:

```
<div class="wrapper-with-intrinsic-ratio">
  <div class="element-to-stretch">
    <div id="main-left">
        <div id="header-logo"></div>
        <div id="content"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="main-right">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper-with-intrinsic-ratio {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
}

.element-to-stretch {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  min-width: 640px;
  min-height: 360px;

  max-width: 1280px;
  max-height: 720px;
}

#main-left {
  background: red;
  width: 38.2%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#header-logo {
  height: 20%;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
}

#content {
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  background: pink;
}

#main-right {
  background: blue;
  width: 61.8%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Possible solution: http://alistapart.com/d/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video/example2.html

The only thing to adapt from this would be to have it vertically center on the page, and have max/min dimensions.